# Route gets unmounted directly, causing a complete re-render for each transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to upgrade an existing application working on React 0.12.* and react-router 0.12.* to React 0.13.3 and react-router.0.13.3.

I now have some issues with the router:

```
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={Application} >
  <Route handler={Home} path="/home" />
  ...
</Route>
```

Every time a component is calling `this.context.router.transitionTo`, `Application` get re-created, not just re-rendered.

Here is the lifecycle of `Application`:

```
- mounted + getInitialState
- unmouted (but somehow still on screen)
- call to router.transitionTo
- mounted + getInitialState
- unmouted
```

This obviously cause the screen to flash.

The router component is just correctly re-rerendered as expected.

I tried to add keys everywhere with no luck.

Am I missing something?